# Why is my query trying to convert problem fields not returned by my source query?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm using a query which searches my data only for records with a 4-digit year. For reference, that base query is:

```
Create view ListDates_FirstFourDigits_ForExport as
/* Find First 4-digit string after $c */
/* For export use a separate query to convert DateFour to INT and to apply year filters. */
SELECT 
    b.bib#,
    i.collection,
    b.text AS Pub260, 
    /* Create DateFour: substring(string, start, length) */
    substring(
        /* The string we're searching is the full text of MARC 260 */
        b.text, 
        /* Find the substring start: */ 
        /* charindex(substring, string) finds the start of subfield $c. */ 
        /* Then add 1, to skip over the "$c" characters. */
        /* Then skip to the first digits: */
        /* patindex ( '%pattern%' , expression ) finds the first digit after $c. */ 
        charindex("c", b.text)+1+    
        patindex(
            "%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%",
            substring(
                /* The string we're searching is the full text of MARC 260 */
                b.text, 
                /* Find the substring start: */ 
                /*charindex(substring, string) finds the start of subfield $c. */ 
                /* Then add 2, to skip over the "$c" characters. */
                charindex("c", b.text)+2,    
                /* Find the substring length: */
                    /* When there are no more subfields after "$c"... */
                        /* ...THEN length is from "$c" to the end of the field. */
                /* ELSE the length is from "$c" to the next subfield */
                CASE
                    WHEN charindex("", b.text, charindex("c", b.text)+2)=0    
                        THEN (len(b.text)+1)-(charindex("c", b.text)+2)    
                    ELSE charindex("", b.text, charindex("c", b.text)+2)
                        -(charindex("c", b.text)+2)    
                END
            )
        ),
        /* We need a length of 4; all of these should be a 4-digit year */
        4
    ) AS DateFour
FROM bib b, item i
WHERE (b.tag = "260" or b.tag = "264")
AND b.bib# = i.bib#
AND (i.collection = "gen" or i.collection = "ref")
AND b.text like '%c%'
AND substring(
        /* The string we're searching is the full text of MARC 260 */
        b.text, 
        /* Find the substring start: */ 
        /* charindex(substring, string) finds the start of subfield $c. */ 
        /* Then add 1, to skip over the "$c" characters. */
        /* Then skip to the first digits: */
        /* patindex ( '%pattern%' , expression ) finds the first digit after $c. */ 
        charindex("c", b.text)+1+    
        patindex(
            "%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%",
            substring(
                /* The string we're searching is the full text of MARC 260 */
                b.text, 
                /* Find the substring start: */ 
                /*charindex(substring, string) finds the start of subfield $c. */ 
                /* Then add 2, to skip over the "$c" characters. */
                charindex("c", b.text)+2,    
                /* Find the substring length: */
                    /* When there are no more subfields after "$c"... */
                        /* ...THEN length is from "$c" to the end of the field. */
                /* ELSE the length is from "$c" to the next subfield */
                CASE
                    WHEN charindex("", b.text, charindex("c", b.text)+2)=0    
                        THEN (len(b.text)+1)-(charindex("c", b.text)+2)    
                    ELSE charindex("", b.text, charindex("c", b.text)+2)
                        -(charindex("c", b.text)+2)    
                END
            )
        ),
        /* We need a length of 4; all of these should be a 4-digit year */
        4
    ) like '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

This query only grabs records with a string of 4-digits in the appropriate field. But when I try to use this data to drive another query, it chokes on records which should be excluded by this query's Where clause. So this query:

```
SELECT 
    bib#, 
    Convert(int, DateFour) AS DateInt
FROM ListDates_FirstFourDigits_ForExport
WHERE Convert(int, DateFour) < 1919
```

gets me this message:

> Syntax error during explicit conversion of VARCHAR value 'a[W' to a
>   INT field. Error occurred after fetching 30 row(s).
>
> 30 Row(s) affected

I understand what it's choking on; in records that aren't filtered out by my search for 4-digit numbers, you might very well see data like that. But those records should be filtered out. Obviously I'm missing something but I don't see what.

Answer (score 1):

Better use `Try_Convert()` so that if the cast succeeds it return the value casted to the specified data type otherwise return a `NULL`.

```
SELECT 
    bib#, 
    Convert(int, DateFour) AS DateInt
FROM ListDates_FirstFourDigits_ForExport
WHERE Try_Convert(int, DateFour) < 1919
```

Comment: Oddly this gets me the message: 
Invalid column name 'int'.

Comment: Using the ListDates_FirstFourDigits_ForExport query I pasted above, I've tried the query you sent on Wednesday. My system doesn't seem to like Try_Convert. I tried a similar query with Try_Converty in the SELECT statement instead, and got the same error:

'SELECT 
    bib#, 
    Try_Convert(int, DateFour) AS DateInt
FROM ListDates_FirstFourDigits_ForExport'

'Invalid column name 'int'.'

Comment: This is a Sybase database, so that may make a difference.

Comment: Yes, the question was tagged TSQL. So I've suggested the answer in context of SQL Server.

Comment: I now know that Sybase uses only a subset of Transact-SQL. Thank you for your help here.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this later, this worked:

```
SELECT 
    bib#, 
    DateFour
FROM ListDates_FirstFourDigits_ForExport
WHERE 
    (CASE
      WHEN DateFour like '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
      THEN Cast(DateFour AS int)
      ELSE Null
    END) < 1920
```